# How to write dynamic variable in beanshell post processor?

Tags: jmeter, void, beanshell, user-defined

We have user defined variable name as "search".

I am using below line to write in csv file in beanshell postprocessor but its showing me "void" in csv file:

print(${search});

please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. [Since JMeter 3.1 you should be using JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) for scripting therefore consider switching to Groovy
2. [Don't refer JMeter Functions and/or Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) in scripts directly as it might cause unexpected behavior or script malfunction. Either use "Parameters" tab or go for code-based equivalents
3. Beanshell [`print()` function](http://www.beanshell.org/manual/bshcommands.html#print) basically writes the value to [STDOUT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_output_(stdout)), if you want to write the value to a file you should do it differently.

Assuming all above you should be using something like:

```
new File("/path/to/your/file.csv") << vars.get("search")
```

More information: [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)